Sympy absolute value derivativ
I've been trying to represent the absolute value derivative using sympy as the one shown in the image. I know that sympy represent it with real and imaginary part, but I need the derivative in function of the absolute value since I'm only working with real numbers. Thanks :)
enter image description here
I just have tried with the sympy functions, but as I mentioned before the derivative of the absolute value is given in complex terms

Use assumptions, like this:
from sympy import *
t = symbols("t")
u = Function("u", real=True)(t)
diff(Abs(u), t)
# sign(u(t))*Derivative(u(t), t)

